# How are labels used with statements that are not a loop?

Tags: javascript, labeled-statements

According to the [ECMAScript 5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), section 12.12, any statement can be labelled - and in a brief test my browser accepted a label before any statement. The spec also states that labels are used exclusively with `break` and `continue` statements, and a quick test revealed that those statements throw an "undefined label" error if the label they reference does not refer to a loop that contains them.

So my question is this: what are labels for statements that are not loops used for? Is there some context in which `break` or `continue` can reference a label that is not a loop?

Comment: Not a dupe, but an interesting, related, and recent question - with some of the answers being somewhat relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782877/using-colons-in-javascript-variable-names-eg-abc

Comment: haha, yeah, I was just reading that. It's what prompted me to ask this.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the break and continue statements can be used within any statement:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch06_11.htm

In which case things like this become legal:

```
function show_alert()
{
    label:
    {
        break label;
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
    alert("hi");
}
```

When show_alert() is called, only the "hi" alert is shown.

As far as I know, this is the only use of the {} code blocks, other than for code styling. (there was a question on here about that, and noone could come up with anything other than readability, but I can't find it now...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735841/whats-the-purpose-of-lonely-code-blocks-in-javascript/8735997#8735997

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But I'm not accepting it as complete (yet), since it doesn't explain why you can label non-block statements (eg `start:var a=1;`).

Comment: You can label non-block statement as well (why not ?). The likely use is for debugging and locating statement in the statement's list. Right now, this feature is not used in browser's debugger, but it does not mean that you can't have a debugger that allows you to check every statement in your program and find it by its labels. In the future, interrupted program execution could resume from a label, the grammar allows this, even if the feature is not there yet.

Comment: @xryl669 Fair enough. I'm not going to change my answer unless it does actually start to be used for something though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can label any statement. You just need to put the statement in curly braces, i.e.

```
{start:var a=1;}
```

this will not show undefined label error.